# Vim rc is completely unfolded on sourcing

Tags: vim

I am using marker based folding for my vimrc. It getting completely unfolded whenever I source it. I am using the the follwoing line to set the folding:

set modeline

set modelines=1

"vim:foldmethod=marker:foldlevel=0

Comment: Is your setting actually getting read and set? What is the output of `:verbose set foldmethod`? That will tell you what your actual foldmethod currently is, and where it was last set.

Comment: foldmetho=marker
    Last set from modeline

Comment: Well that looks right. And foldlevel?